# How can I open more than one index in a given file/handle using a LSM tree library?

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I am trying to use the [SQLite4 LSM library](https://sqlite.org/src4/doc/trunk/www/lsmusr.wiki) as a separate entity. 
How does one open more than one index in a given file/handle? Sqlite3 stores all indexes and tables in a single file, so I assume the LSM library has the ability to support 2 or more indexes within a single file. If not, I just need to know so that I can open two LSM trees. Nothing in the manuals and can't find an example.

Comment: Try to formatting your questions properly so that others can read it easier.

Comment: What is this *LSM library*?

Comment: Are you talking about SQLite4?